Auto Fill Google Doc from Google Form Using Google Apps Script
I am trying to auto send an email when a new respond from Google Form.
I have a template from Google Doc, a Form and a Sheet from the form respond. I copied a script as below:
function autoFillGoogleDocsFromForm(e) {
var hoten = e.values[1];
var sodienthoai = e.values[2];
var ngaysinh = e.values[3];
var image = e.values[4];

var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("<<doc template ID>>");
var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("<< folder ID>>");

var copy = templateFile.makeCopy('Ho va Ten ' + HoTen, templateResponseFolder);
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
var body = doc.getBody();

body.replaceText("{{HoTen}}", hotenoTen);
body.replaceText("{{Sdt}}", sodienthoai);
body.replaceText("{{Birthday}}", ngaysinh);
body.replaceText("{{ImageUrl}}", image);

doc.saveAndClose();
}

But when I run the code, an error was show up:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')
autoFillGoogleDocsFromForm    @ Code.gs:2

I watched videos on Youtube but don't know why It is wrong.
Can someone please explain to me why? and how to solve this?


Hi Hendrik Bezuidenhout,   Are you running this code from the script
editor (by clicking the ► play button)?   If so, that would explain
the error, as the code is not meant to be run from the script editor,
and it is normal for the error to occur like this.   Scripts like
these, that have a specified event-object (like e on function
onEdit(e) {...}), are triggered (automatically) if edits take place in
the spreadsheet. The script captures the edit (event) and uses the
event-object (e) in the script.   If you try to ► run the function
from the Apps Scripts Editor, then no such event object (e) is
captured because no edit took place, and, hence all properties
(e.range, e.value, ...) of that event are undefined.   So, you must
close the Apps Scripts Editor, and edit your document in order for the
edit (event) to be captured.   I hope that clarifies the situation.

This is the answer. Thanks all for reading.
